Arduino Nano spontaneously stops working and disconnects from computer
I'm trying to implement an Arkanoid game on a 16x16 RGB matrix (the library is Adafruit_NeoMatrix). The blocks are 2x2 squares, and there are 3 rows with 8 blocks in each. The current state of the game (which of the blocks are still present) is stored in a 8x3 int array called blocks. 0 means no block, and 1–3 mean a block with a specific color (the color is randomly selected at setup).
Here's the function I use for rendering the blocks (SIZE_X is 16, BLOCKS_HEIGHT is 3, and matrix is the Adafruit_NeoMatrix instance used to control the matrix):
int blocks[BLOCKS_HEIGHT][SIZE_X / 2] = {
  { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
  { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 },
  { 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 }
};

void renderBlocks() {
  Serial.println("renderBlocks");

  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_X / 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < BLOCKS_HEIGHT; j++) {
      if (blocks[j][i] > 0) {
        uint16_t color;
        
        switch (blocks[j][i]) {
          case 1:
            color = matrix.Color(200, 0, 0);
            break;
          case 2:
            color = matrix.Color(0, 200, 0);
            break;
          case 3:
            color = matrix.Color(0, 0, 200);
            break;
        }

        matrix.drawPixel(i * 2, j * 2, color);
        matrix.drawPixel(i * 2 + 1, j * 2, color);
        matrix.drawPixel(i * 2, j * 2 + 1, color);
        matrix.drawPixel(i * 2 + 1, j * 2 + 1, color);
      }
    }
  }

  matrix.show();
}

In a real game, it would be called each time the ball knocks out a block, but as for now it's all I have implemented, because the following issue is stopping me. (Currently it's called one time per second in the loop.)
Here is what appears in the serial monitor:

When I plug in the Arduino, it waits for some time, then shows this on the matrix, prints "rend" and disconnects. (Looks like it doesn't finish executing Serial.println("renderBlocks") in the beginning of my function.) Please note that the blocks are displayed in the wrong order: green, then red, then blue, although the hardcoded array means red, green, blue. Also please note that the blue blocks blink (it's more noticeable than on the video). What I'm asking for is an explanation of all those weird things.
The Arduino doesn't seem to be bricked (everything else I load into it works). The matrix works correctly, too (nothing strange happens in other sketches working with it).
Below is the loop:
void loop() {
  if (millis() - lastRenderTime >= 1000) {
    lastRenderTime = millis();
    renderBlocks();
  }
}

I cannot use delay because in a real game I will have to listen to the control buttons. And I didn't forget to do Serial.begin(9600) at setup.
EDIT: Arduino doesn't switch off completely (the power LED is on), it just disconnects.
EDIT #2: lastRenderTime is unsigned long.

I think your power supply is not sufficient for your whole setup.

@tepalia The power supply is my computer, and that's enough for Arduino + matrix, as other sketches that deal with the matrix work.

what data type is lastRenderTime?

@Juraj unsigned long

please do not post a picture of text ... post the text instead ... you copied and pasted the code, do the same with the serial monitor

@jsotola Is there any text besides "rend"?

it makes no difference how much text there is ... some people use screen readers,  and they cannot read text in a picture

@jsotola "When I plug in the Arduino, it waits for some time, then shows this on the matrix, prints "rend" and disconnects." — the picture was fully described in text.

is something wired to pins D0 or D1?

@Juraj No, they're free

It honestly really sounds like a power problem. Are you powering the project via USB? How many LEDs are on at the same time (each NeoPixel is actually 3 LEDs, 1 per color)? It looks like you would have 3x8=24 blocks of 4 pixels each making 96pixels, each pixel being one color a bit under full brightness. So lets say 15mA per pixel, means 1.44A drawn by the matrix. That is a bit much for a USB port of a PC (without negotiating a higher output power with the USB controller).

@chrisl I implemented a fire animation on that matrix, which took up the same space, and it worked well.

Sorry, but "a fire animation" is very fuzzy information. For this topic we would need to talk about current values. You can verify that: use the builtin LED blinking in setup (so you see a reset of the microcontroller) and power the projekt with a USB charger (rated at least 2A). Otherwise I would try finding the exact spot, where its resets by showing the LEDs on each inner loop iteration and adding a delay, so that you can visually see at what block the reset happens

By "Arduino Nano" you're referring to one of the original ATmega168/328P-based boards and not another of the many other boards now carrying that name?

@timemage ATmega 328P old bootloader

How many pixels does your "fire animation" switch on at the same time? Compare this to the number of pixels switched on with the game. (Please [edit] your question to add such clarifications. Additional stuff is hard to find in the comments and easily overviewed.)

@chrisl My matrix supports an additional power supply. I'll try connecting it, but not today

I think you need to revise the  renderBlocks function with additional debug statements and power checks.

This issue was resolved by connecting an additional power supply. Thanks to everyone who participated!

Unless you post a schematic or picture of the hardware setup, I assume that the power from the led matrix is drawn from the arduino or the USB port. Almost always an arduino resets in the middle of an operation like that, it is because of power drop or short circuit. If you have a scope you can monitor the input voltage of the Arduino. I suspect that the power drops too much.
Try to power the matrix from its own power supply and connect the GND of the power supply and the usb/arduino together to create a common ground.

Yes, I've already resolved the issue this way.
